# Error: No puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado netstandard

Tags: xamarin.forms

me acaban de pasar un proyecto en xamarin forms, lo descargué de su repositorio, y cuando restauré los paquetes nugets, me salen con un icono de admiración, entonces lo que hice fue desinstalarlos y volverlos a instalar manualmente, pero aun así siguen saliendo los iconos de admiración, y me salen tres errores peculiares, que no encuentro solución en google, espero alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo:

Ésta es la imagen del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Limpia todo el proyecto y vuelvelo a compilar.

> Compilar -> Compilación por lotes -> Seleccionar Todo -> Limpiar.

A veces también debes de cerrar el proyecto y volverlo a cargar.